# correct method PUT WebRequest() in MQL4

Tags: mql4

I attempted to update a JSON at `myjson.com`, using the `WebRequest()`, resulting in a failure.

> ```
> return result: 2018.05.22 23:54:44.401    webreq NZDCAD,H1: Status code: 404, error: 4000
> ```

I want to change name from "John" to "Labu"

My code is like the following:

```
void postJson()
{
   char post[], result[];

   string headers = "Content-Type: application/json\r\n";
   string obj     = "'data:{\"name\":\"Labu\"}'"; 

   StringToCharArray( obj, post, 0, WHOLE_ARRAY ); // Must specify string length;
                                                   // otherwise array has
                                                   // terminating null character in it
   int res = WebRequest( "POST",
                         "https://api.myjson.com/bins/tj8e2",
                         "PUT",
                          NULL,
                          10000,
                          post,
                          ArraySize( post ),
                          result,
                          headers
                          );
   Print( "Status code: " , res, ", error: ", GetLastError() );
   Print( "Server response: ", CharArrayToString( result ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string obj="'data:{\"name\":\"Labu\"}'";
```

you do not need the **`'`**-chars
you must make sure that the address is valid and that it is added to the list of allowed web sites ( inside the MetaTrader Terminal configuration setup panel ).

Answer (score 0):

remove POST and put PUT,
read your own code:  `WebRequest( "POST",`
should be,  `WebRequest( "PUT",`

You are using POST method still.

Here:

```
    int  WebRequest(
   const string      method,           // HTTP method 
   const string      url,              // URL
   const string      cookie,           // cookie
   const string      referer,          // referer
   int               timeout,          // timeout
   const char        &data[],          // the array of the HTTP message body
   int               data_size,        // data[] array size in bytes
   char              &result[],        // an array containing server response data
   string            &result_headers   // headers of server response
   );
```

Now would be a good time to also mention mt4 don't support PUT or DELETE only POST and GET ;)